# create-react-app Failing to create a new React app in windows 10

Tags: reactjs

I have `Create-react-app version 1.4.3` installed. When I try to create a new App , I get the following messages in the command prompt. Please help me find and fix the issue.

```
C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server>create-react-app client

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server\client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server\client\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
node lib/post_install.js

npm ERR! path C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server\client\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server\client\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server\client\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'C:\\Users\\GSI-KOL\\Desktop\\server\\client\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\GSI-KOL\\Desktop\\server\\client\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\GSI-KOL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-08T13_08_03_705Z-debug.log
    
Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.
    
Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting client / from C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server
Done.
    
C:\Users\GSI-KOL\Desktop\server>
```

Comment: Try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)

Answer (score 21):

I was faced this same problem . It is due to the issue with npm .

please run the following command in command Line

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
create-react-app <project Name>
```

If your problem still exist then switch from npm to yarn

run the following commands, it solved my problem

```
npm install -g yarn

yarn global add create-react-app

create-react-app <projectname>
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you need admin privileges to write some of the generated files. Can you create a terminal instance with administrator rights then reissue the command?

Answer (score 6):

You probably had "create-react-app" running before, which was the problem in my case anyway. The way I solved this was using 
`npm cache clean --force` and ran `create-react-app my-app` again.

Comment: @Ssenyonjo it cleans the cache of npm

Answer (score 4):

I suspect NPM has an issue. However, this was how I was able to resolve it

Follow this steps:

1. `npm install -g yarn`
2. `yarn global add create-react-app`
3. `Create-react-app <projectname>`

Answer (score 3):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then try

```
npm create-react-app navigate
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same issue and I rectified it using the comment
given below:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

After this comment try:
npx create-react-app project_name

Comment: Please, dont post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just run this one command to resolve issue:

`sudo chown -R 1001:1001 "/home/<user_name>/.npm"`

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the network issues try to download all dependency one by one or try to clean  cache **"npm cache clean --force"** after this try to create an app
**npx create-react-app <app__name>**. But your internet connection should be stable.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the `npm cache clean --force` and the yarn route but, neither worked. What worked for me was running Powershell as Administrator then entering:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
npm install -g yarn

yarn global add create-react-app

create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this was solved to me with these steps:

1. Be sure that you have the **lastest version of Node.js installed**. (https://nodejs.org/)
2. **npm install -g** *create-react-app*
3. **create-react-app client-app --use-npm** or **npx create-react-app client-app --use-npm**

i hope it helped..

Comment: thanks, re-installing the create-react-app was the missing link for me

Answer (score 1):

this should work
`npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue, here is how I fixed it :
 1. I first cleaned my cache using the --force keyword
 2. I reinstalled create-react-app globally
 3. I recreated my app.

Illustration:

1. clean your cache

```js
    npm cache clean --force
```

2. Reinstall create-react-app globally

```js
    npm i -g create-react-app
```

3. Recreate your app

```js
    create-react-app .
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
npm install -g yarn
```

then this

```
npx create-react-app my-project
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, i wasn't connected to the internet when i tried to run 'create-react-app', so i connected and tried it, it worked, i'm guessing it needed to install some packages from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\CM\Downloads\react\github-profile.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! path C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 

v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1fa335b1
0893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec65545008a3cad93d00f806

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996
b1fa335b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec6
5545008a3cad93d00f806'
npm ERR! { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1f 
a335b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec6554500
8a3cad93d00f806']

npm ERR! cause:
npm ERR! { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1
fa335b10893d67f7339e4 
af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec65545008a3cad93d00f806'
npm ERR! errno: -4048,
npm ERR! code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR! path:
npm ERR! 'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content- 


npm ERR! stack:
npm ERR! 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996
b1fa335b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015
eec65545008a3cad93d00f806'',
npm ERR! errno: -4048,
npm ERR! code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR! path:
npm ERR! 'C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content- 
v2\sha512\36\c6\c3e97514319bc1c6d40026e58325e782e1016c996b1fa335
b10893d67f7339e4af62bb688c0da2aaca839d4c9d51e2eb015eec65545008a3cad93
d00f806',
npm ERR! parent: 'postcss-image-set-function' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a
text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double- 
check thenpm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or 
try  running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not 
recommended).
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\CM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-22T10_
27_19_722Z-debug.log


Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react- 
scripts   has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting github-profile/ from C:\Users\CM\Downloads\reactDone.``
```

i was facing similar error but i tried to run create-react-app command many times and finally it was created , this was the problem with my internet connection. check your inernet connection

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with the same problem, According to the error, you have a problem with your npm.

Try this command

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "<location of npm>/.npm"
```

just take an example of my command

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/vidit/.npm"
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `npm cache clean --force`

Works 100%

In my case, it happened when I aborted a wrong command I initiated.

Then I ran `npm cache clean --force` and the cache was cleaned; after that, I ran my `npx create-react-app` and it worked perfectly as it should.

Quick tip: Uninstall create-react-app from your machine like so, `npm un -g create-react-app` and run `npx create-react-app` instead of `npm create-react-app` any time you want to create a new react app.

Reason: npx will always use the latest version of create-react-app to create a new react app for your project, and npx uninstalls/removes the create-react-app package from your machine when it's done.

Don't worry, it takes about 20 seconds to install the create-react-app package, so...

Do not forget to `npm cache clean --force` when `npx create-react-app` goes bananas (i.e. refuses to work).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I did these to solve the problem;

1. npm clean cache --force..

this didn't work... I returned a warning **npm WARN using --forcing recommended protection disable.**

2. I ignored that and did and reinstalled create-react-app globally by running;
   npm i -g create-react-app
3. I created my app(project name) by running;
   create-react-app my-app-name

I believe this should work for you..

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue.
I Try this But it does not work for me
`npm cache clean --force`

So uninstall Node
and install the latest version. It's worked for me
Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by changing the timeout time to greater than 30000
`npx create-react-app appname -timeout=90000`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the above mentioned worked for me. What fixed the problem was updating the npm:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

I did this because in the new LTS version (16.15.1) of NodeJS, npm was updated from 8.5.5 to 8.13.2.

Answer (score 0):

just instead using the git-bash as a terminal use Windows powershell as a terminal it will work

Answer (score 0):

in your system go to this location

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming

and inside that you will find a folder named "npm" delete that folder

and try npx create-react-app command again. conform it will work

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar and unlike others cleaning cache by using (npm cache clean --force) wasn't working out for me

this helped me instead
npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm

hope this does the trick for anyone who isn't getting result from cleaning cache

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

run npm install -g create-react-app (it will install create-react-app globally)

then create your app by running npx create-react-app [project-name]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

This was my error:

```
3695 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts"
3696 verbose node v6.10.3
3697 verbose npm  v6.4.1
3698 error code Z_BUF_ERROR
3699 error errno -5
3700 error zlib: unexpected end of file
```

This solved the issue:

```
npm cache clean --force and ran create-react-app my-app
```